# ScrollPane doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, scrollpane

I have a problem with ScrollPane and TextArea I put a scroll there and when I try to type in the TextArea it doesn't scroll it gets wider. Here you got the code for it:

```
package interface_Components;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class chatComponent extends JFrame {

    private JTextField chatInput;
    private JTextArea chatOutput;
    private JScrollPane chatScroll;
    private JButton sendButton;
    private JButton newRoomButton;
    private JButton joinRoomButton;
    private JButton inviteButton;
    private JList roomsList;
    private JList usersList;

    public chatComponent() {
        JFrame loggedInWindow = new JFrame("Yikes!");
        chatInput = new JTextField("Type here");
        chatOutput = new JTextArea("Type here and press enter many times scroll doesnt work I dont know why");
        chatScroll = new JScrollPane(chatOutput);
        sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        newRoomButton = new JButton("New Room");
        joinRoomButton = new JButton("Join Room");
        inviteButton = new JButton("Invite");
        roomsList = new JList();
        usersList = new JList();

        chatInput.selectAll();
        chatScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        chatScroll.setAutoscrolls(true);

        chatOutput.setRows(6);
        chatOutput.setLineWrap(true);
        chatOutput.setAutoscrolls(true);

        loggedInWindow.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel centerInternal_1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel centerInternal_2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel centerInternal_3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JPanel eastInternal_1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel eastInternal_2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0, 5, 5));

        centerInternal_3.add(chatInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerInternal_3.add(sendButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        centerInternal_2.add(chatOutput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerInternal_2.add(chatScroll, BorderLayout.EAST);
        centerInternal_2.add(centerInternal_3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        centerInternal_1.add(centerInternal_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        centerInternal_1.add(roomsList, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        centerPanel.add(centerInternal_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        eastInternal_1.add(usersList, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        eastInternal_2.add(newRoomButton);
        eastInternal_2.add(joinRoomButton);
        eastInternal_2.add(inviteButton);

        eastPanel.add(eastInternal_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        eastPanel.add(eastInternal_2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        loggedInWindow.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        loggedInWindow.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        loggedInWindow.setVisible(true);
        loggedInWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loggedInWindow.setSize(800, 600);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chatComponent cc = new chatComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: Java has naming standards. Following them makes your code more understandable for you and for others. No underscores in package names, class names written in camel case, and so on. Here is a complete list: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: You should share your solution via an answer (if you're solution is different from dogbane's). That way, someone else may benefit from your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are adding `chatOutput` to the CENTER of the panel and `chatScroll` to the EAST. I don't think this is what you want.

You need to add `chatScroll` to the CENTER like this:

```
//centerInternal_2.add(chatOutput, BorderLayout.CENTER); //don't add chatOutput
centerInternal_2.add(chatScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
centerInternal_2.add(centerInternal_3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```